# Difference between wsl.localhost and wsl:Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: Image showing the problem]

I installed wsl2 and vscode in my computer. I am trying to run some code thats in the folder "home/raunakk/MSc_project". But when I try to open the folder on vs code, it shows me two folders.

I donot understand the difference between wsl.localhost and wsl:Ubuntu as shown in the picture. Can I delete/uninstall one of them?
It is confusing because my code seems to run when I am in wsl:Ubuntu and not from wsl.localhost.
I am new to wsl, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same WSL directory.

When you use `wsl.localhost`, you are accessing that directoy from Windows.

When you use wsl:Ubuntu, you are using VSCode WSL extension, so accessing that directory directly from WSL.

Comment: Do they store different versions of the files inside them?

Comment: I don't think so (not 100% sure). But you should just use wsl:Ubuntu to avoid confusion.